# Redirect from https to http in Azure Web App service

Tags: http, azure, redirect, iis, https

I have a website which supports both HTTP and HTTPS (with a valid certificate) but unfortunally for internal issues with some external services, the HTTPS configuration is not ready yet to go in production.

I would like to redirect for now through IIS (`web.config` file) every https request to http.

I found in the official doc, the code to redirect from http to https but not the inverse. So I tried to convert it but IIS does not actually redirect:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Azure App Service websites supports the IIS URL rewrite module so what you are trying to do should work. I think the only thing you got wrong is the conditon, you are adding a condition for a `Server Variable` called `HTTP`, but there is no `HTTP`, only `HTTPS` which is either `ON` or `OFF`. [See this for full list of IIS Server Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx). So, just flip it and instead of checking if HTTP is OFF (which doesn't exist and will never be true), **check if HTTPS is ON**

```xml
<rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```