# How can I stop my Azure website from redirecting all HTTP traffic to HTTPS automatically?

Tags: .net, azure, redirect, https, active-directory

We have a web app in Microsoft **Azure shared service** and one of us changed something *"probably enabled Active Directory"* that forced all HTTP traffic to be redirected to HTTPS.

We do not have a certificate nor can add one *"our Azure plan does not support SSL"*. So, now all our clients get the *(your connection is not secure)* error message that makes us looking like an illegitimate company.

Thank you for help us.

PS: we searched all over Azure portal for and the only option we found at **(TLS/SSL settings)** was **(HTTPS Only)** switch and it doesn't matter if it's on or off. still all traffic is https.

Comment: It's 2019. Not using SSL is what will make you "look like an illegitimate company".

Comment: Exactly as @Joseph Sible said. There's very little excuse these days to NOT use SSL seeing as you can even get free certificates. I hope that your clients do not have a means of logging into your unencrypted site.

Comment: Guys, no one is logging into the website. it's just a static page that has our phone lines and location,
I don't believe 56 USD per month is a viable cost just to secure one page.

Comment: And we have bought the 70$ certificate from Microsoft just to find out that we cannot use it unless we pay additional 40$ a month.

Comment: You don't need to pay Microsoft for a certificate. Let's Encrypt will give you one for free, that also auto-renews for free forever.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it gave me exceptions. and I think now that even if I could do it, Azure wont allow me to add the certificate.

Comment: Hi. If you are a static web page. You can host it on Azure blob.storage. Then configure SSL for the blob. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-custom-domain

Answer (score 0):

Although the HTTPS to HTTP switch is definitely **not recommended**, you can try using the workaround mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42046852/10805761) comment. Quoting it again here:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Also, do note that you are not able to use SSL as you're on the **Shared** ASP, and would have to bump it to **Basic** at the very least to be able to use it, and hence the pricing. The same has been detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173582/10805761) as well. For learning more about the capabilities and limits available within App Service Plans, visit [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/) link.

Some more references:

- [Remove Azure SSL binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173582/10805761)
- [Configure an SSL certificate for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site)

Hope this helps.

Comment: For a redirect from HTTPS to HTTP to actually work, you'd have to have HTTPS already working, so there's no point to this.

Comment: @JosephSible is right.
I tried the code and got "Too many redirects" error.
Apparently there's a code or switch that redirects all HTTP to HTTPS that causes a loop